# Loading a language file in oo php

Tags: php, file, static, load

So i am new to oo php and i-m building a sample app for learning purpses , one thing i must do is load a language file according to some settings
The code, as you will discover below is divided between two classes , a settings class witch should load the language file and another class in this case "contact" witch should read the array in the language files and display the propper message.
this is the Settings class
the lang variable sets the default language it can take 2 values at the moment : ro- for romanian and en - for english ,

```
    class Settings
{
  static public $lang = 'ro';
  static public $load;

  static public function get_language()
   {
    if(self::$lang == 'ro')
    {
      self::$load = require 'ro.php';
    }
    elseif(self::$lang == 'en')
    {
     self::$load = require 'en.php';
    }
    return self::$load;
   }

}
```

The second class :

```
class Contact extends Settings {
   //proprietati

   public $nume;
   public $subiect;
   public $mesaj;
   public $dincs;


   //comportament - metode

   public function __construct()
   {
     //$this->dincs = 'Din construct';
     parent::get_language();
   }


   public function write_file()
   {

     if(empty($this->nume))
     {
       return $mess['name_error'];
     }
     else
     {
       $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
       fwrite($fp, $this->nume.".".$this->subiect .".". $this->mesaj."|".$this->dincs ."|".parent::$load);
       fclose($fp);

       return $mess['file_written'];
     }
   }

}
```

A sample from the language file:

```
   $mess = array ("name_error"  => "You must insert your name",
                  "file_written" => "the file has been written",

   );
```

I have looked up on google , and tried some other stuff and can't seem to get it to work , and that may be because i am approaching this problem incorectly.
Plese help.

Comment: Is there any errors? What didn't work?

Comment: it gives a notice that the variable $mess is not defined, and does not display the messages, the suggestion below might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
class Settings
{
    protected $language = 'ro';
    protected $load;

    public function setLanguage($language = 'ro')
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        // file_get_contents()
        $this->load = require($this->language . '.php');
    }

    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

}

class Contact extends Settings 
{
   protected $name;
   protected $subject;
   protected $message;
   protected $dincs;
   protected $settingsObject;

   // set all the properties below...

   public function setName($name)
   {
        $this->name = $name;
   }   

   public function setSubject($subject)
   {
        $this->subject = $subject;
   }   

   public function setMessage($message)
   {
        $this->message = $message;
   }   

   public function setDincs($dincs)
   {
        $this->dincs = $dincs;
   }

   // get all the properties...
   public function getName()
   {
        return $this->name;
   }

   // This function only accepts an instance of Settings as the parameter
   public function setSettingsObject(Settings $settings)
   {    
        $this->settingsObject = $settings;
   }

   public function writeContentsToFile()
   {
        // if there is nothing in name, throw a new exception
        if (empty($this->name))
        {
            throw new Exception('name has not been set! Set name before calling '. __METHOD__);
        }
        else
        {
           // get the file
           $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');

           // formatted string
           $contents = sprintf('%s . %s . %s | %s | %s', $this->name, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->dincs, $this->settingsObject->getLanguage());

           // write to the file
           fwrite($fp, $contents);

           // close the handler
           fclose($fp);

           return ('File written! Contents written: ' . $contents);
        }
    }
}


// instantiate settings
$settings = new Settings();
$settings->setLanguage('en');

// instantiate contact and set the settings object
$contact = new Contact();
$contact->setName('Joe Smith'); // if this is not set, ::writeContentsToFile will throw an Exception
$contact->setSettingsObject($settings);

// try and catch the Exception that ::writeContentsToFile may throw
try 
{
    echo $contact->writeContentsToFile();
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    var_dump($exception);
}
```

?>
`

Answer (score 0):

```
self::$load = require 'en.php';
```

You assign here a return value from the file inclusion to `self::$load`; not the variable `$mess` you defined in your language file.

So, there are two ways now: return the array `$mess` (`return $mess;`) from the language file.

Or you can just write:

```
require 'en.php';
self::$load = $mess;
```

---

Little side note: I'd check in your `Settings::getLanguage()` method `if (self::$load)` and return then the `self::$load` variable instead of refetching the language file…)